# Subscribing to programs

Tags: php

**What I am doing:**

I am working on a system where users can subscribe to a specific program. The users can do this on a subscription page. Once the users have subscribed to a program, that specific program will be displayed on the download page. Which is another page on my website. Subscribing can be done just by clicking on the "Abonneer" button next to the program (you can compare it to subscribing on a Youtube channel).
It looks like this:

[image]

The program the user has subscribed to is displayed on the download page. Which looks like this:

[image]

**My initial idea:**

My initial idea was; that as soon as the user clicks on the "Abonneer" button, a query is made. The query would go like this:
SELECT * FROM databasename WHERE id = 2
The program with that id would then be selected and it would then be displayed on the download page.
**The problem:**

There are a few problems with my idea. The first problem is that I have one line of code that displays ALL the content in the database. Which makes it hard to choose just one program out of the database and then select it. The code that displays all the data from the database is:

`<th>Programma:</th><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $retrieved_data->Anaam;?></td>`

The second problem is that I cannot make a query that selects an id from the database. That would not be possible since there are many programs and each of them has a different id.

**My question:**

Do you happen to know how I can make a piece of code that allows the user to subscribe to a program, and that the program he/she has subscribed to is selected from the database and displayed on the download page? It would really help me if you showed code example.

**My code:**

```
My subscibe.php code:
<?php

global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpex_programma";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM wpex_programma;" );
//print_r($retrieve_data);
?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table>
<?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) { ?>
<tr>
     <th>Programma:</th><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $retrieved_data->Anaam;?></td>
     <th><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Abonneer" /></th>
  </tr>
<?php 
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  //Do this code when the button is clicked on.
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

**My expectations:**

I expect to be able to subscribe to a program, and that the program I have subscribed to is selected and is viewed on another page.
Greetings,
Parsa

Comment: _“The first problem is that I have one line of code that displays ALL the content in the database.”_ - no, you don’t. The line you mentioned outputs the data for _one_ record in your result set. It is placed inside a loop, so that that happens for all records - but it still happens for each record individually.

Comment: I don’t see how one could give you a “code example” in a case like this, without pretty much presenting the complete solution on a silver platter already. You should really approach this differently. Start by figuring out what _exactly_ needs to happen in the background, before you start coding. If you want an _actual_ subscription service, then you need to start by storing the user’s choice in the database. Just _displaying_ the project the user selected in a form on the next page, is not a “subscription” to begin with.

Comment: The user his choice is already saved in the database. It is then displayed on the subscribe page @CBroe

Comment: Also, if I want press on the subscribe button. It would need to select the program to which the user is subscribed. Like 22nl. Which cannot happen with this loop. So it would still not work

Comment: You are not making much sense here. First you say, storing the user’s choice into the database was already implemented, then you seem to say that part still needs implementing directly in the next comment …?

Comment: The programs are already saved in the database. When the user subscribes to a program, the program will be selected from the database and then displayed on the download page. Only problem will then be that all users can see that data on the download page. But that is a different subject. @CBroe

Comment: _“The programs are already saved in the database.”_ - I did not say programs … I said the user’s actual choice of a specific programm is what you need to store somewhere. _“Only problem will then be that all users can see that data on the download page. But that is a different subject.”_ - no, it is not. You need to store the user’s selection, so that you can _connect_ it to that specific user again later on. Before you don’t do that, starting to tacklle the rest of this doesn’t even make much sense.

Comment: So if user A subscribes to program B, that would need to be stored in the database? Then I would still need to code that users can subscribe to some program. So that after that the choice is saved in the database. Which is one of my main questions. @CBroe

Comment: Do you want to be able to show the info that the user subscribed to B only one single time, directly after they submitted the form? Or do you want to be able to still show them that they did subscribe to B _tomorrow_, without them having to submit the same form with the same choice again? Well if it is the latter, then _of course_ you need to store this information somewhere. How can that even be a question?

Comment: Yes I know it would need to be saved. But then again, I would still need to know how to code that the user can subsctibe to a program. Which I still do not know how to do. In this case, as soon as a user subscribes to a program, it would need to be inserted in the database and then displayed. But I do not know how to allow them to subscribe. @CBroe

Comment: Your programms probably have some sort of record ID in the database, and are not identifable just by name alone. So read that ID from the database as well, and create a way for the user to submit that ID to your backend. The simplest way to do that here, would be to not use `<input type="submit">`, but a `button` element - that can have a submission value, that is different from its display text. Start writing code that receives this submitted ID, and then store it somewhere. If you have no database table told hold this information yet, then you need to create one.

Comment: (It looks like you are partially using WordPress functionality here though, but then you are programming your own solution within that, that does not do things “the WordPress way”. That is probably not the most clever approach to begin with.)

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I will work on the suggestion you gave me. Right now I am creating a table in which the choices of each user are saved. So thanks for that suggestion. I also have a table in which all the programs are saved. Those programs are display on the page. When the user subscribes on a program, the program the user has subscribed to will go in another table in which his user choices are saved. The choices will then be showed on the download page. @CBroe